# Mass Export outlook letters with ConversationID

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server, mapi

I need to extract all emails with standard outlook fields (from/to/subject/date, including category and most importantly, ConversationID) into Excel/csv.
I'm using MS Office 2016, no idea about version of Exchange server.

I tried several ways to do so on my mailbox:
1) exported data through standard outlook interface
2) exported data into MS access via standard export master
3) extracted data to MS PowerBI from MS Exchange directly

In all 3 cases I wasn't able to get ConversationID (PowerBI extract had some ID but it was not ConversationID)

Now I understand that it should be extracted through MAPI somehow, but I'm totally illiterate on this topic. Some searches advised to use special software for that, like Transcend, but it's obviously too expensive for one user :)

I also found VBA code to get data into Excel directly but it is not working for me: 
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1739523
Also found this nice explanation what is ConversationID - might be helpful for others intrested in topic: 
https://www.meridiandiscovery.com/how-to/e-mail-conversation-index-metadata-computer-forensics/

Comment: What exactly is not working in your existing code?

Comment: getting error `User-defined type not defined` while execution on this part `Public ns As Outlook.Namespace` @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: That simply means you did not add Outlook to your project references.

Comment: bbut how to do so?

Comment: Where is your code running?

Comment: I'm trying this VBA on Excel 2016

Comment: So did you add Outlook to your VBA project references (Tools | References)?

Comment: ooo. I now did and it worked for several records till get stopepd by error
---------------------------
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x003F0102" is unknown or cannot be found.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: was using message dated "31 Oct 14 06:09" from this link http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1739523 Basically the last VBA piece on that page

Comment: It means that particular item does not have the PR_RECEIVED_BY_ENTRYID property. Your code must handle situations like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code to get you started, I already had something similar to your ask. The code is commented, but feel free to ask questions :)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub getEmails()
On Error GoTo errhand:

    'Create outlook objects and select a folder
    Dim outlook     As Object: Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim ns          As Object: Set ns = outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

    'This option open a new window for you to select which folder you want to work with
    Dim olFolder    As Object: Set olFolder = ns.pickFolder
    Dim emailCount  As Long: emailCount = olFolder.Items.Count
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim myArray     As Variant
    Dim item        As Object

    ReDim myArray(4, (emailCount - 1))

    For i = 1 To emailCount
        Set item = olFolder.Items(i)
        '43 is olMailItem, only consider this type of email message
        'I'm assuming you only want items with a conversationID
        'Change the logic here to suite your specific needs
        If item.Class = 43 And item.ConversationID <> vbNullString Then
            'Using an array to write to excel in one go
            myArray(0, i - 1) = item.Subject
            myArray(1, i - 1) = item.SenderName
            myArray(2, i - 1) = item.To
            myArray(3, i - 1) = item.CreationTime
            myArray(4, i - 1) = item.ConversationID
        End If
    Next

    'Adding headers, then writing the data to excel
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A1") = "Subject"
        .Range("B1") = "From"
        .Range("C1") = "To"
        .Range("D1") = "Created"
        .Range("E1") = "ConversationID"
        .Range("A2:E" & (emailCount + 1)).Value = TransposeArray(myArray)
    End With

    Exit Sub

errhand:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
End Sub

'This function is used to bypass the limitation of -
'application.worksheetfunction.transpose
'If you have too much data added to an array you'll get a type mismatch
'Found here - http://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/transposing.htm
Public Function TransposeArray(myArray As Variant) As Variant
    Dim X           As Long
    Dim Y           As Long
    Dim Xupper      As Long: Xupper = UBound(myArray, 2)
    Dim Yupper      As Long: Yupper = UBound(myArray, 1)
    Dim tempArray   As Variant

    ReDim tempArray(Xupper, Yupper)

    For X = 0 To Xupper
        For Y = 0 To Yupper
            tempArray(X, Y) = myArray(Y, X)
        Next
    Next

    TransposeArray = tempArray
End Function
```

Comment: it works, but 1) only for Inbox folder, when I try to use "Sent" or whole mailbox  its not working. 2) Conversation id is not full (only first "base" 34 symbols". Actually that convID would fit for me, but it doesn't shows full-lenght ConvID, only the "base" string. Is it possible to get full-lenght convID? Asking out of curiosity.

Comment: I'm glad it's a working example. You can adapt this to meet your needs. Please mark as closed

Comment: Fully worked for me. Still categoryID coming in not full lenght but that's fine for my particular task

Comment: Hey Ryan, I tried this code once again today (doing it yearly) and while Sent folder extracted just fine, when I try to use it on "Inbox" folder, excel freezes for a while and then nothing happens (empty worksheet). Again, it's working on Sent or Drafts folder, but not working on Inbox.. My assumption is that Inbox has too many items (even though I tried to change local replica site horizon into 6months instead 1 year, I really receiving a lot of emails lately). Any chance to workaround on it?

Comment: Without seeing the scenario it is probably too many emails. Use the `Restrict` method to breakup the Inbox. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-restrict-method-outlook